# Create a Report of All Clients with no Contacts

Tags: reporting, contact, standard

I need to create a Standard SF Report to display all Clients with no Contacts ? How can I check the criteria in the Report ? I tried few things but it didn't work. Any help on this is appreciated

Comment: What is Client?

Comment: Are you meant to say Accounts with no contacts? Then Accounts reports should work on this. You could also try custom report type.

Comment: yes apologies, I used the renamed term. So I meant Accounts with no Contacts. I added the criteria for All Accounts and Filtered by  :
Contact ID equals ""  (Thinking that this will filter the Accounts which doesnt have a Contact ID) but it doesn't display any records although there are Accounts without Contacts

Comment: You can follow this link: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000003804&language=en_US&type=1

Comment: @user28452 yes that worked!

Comment: I have posted that in the Answers please accept it so that other users aware of it.

Answer (score 4):

Create a report on Account and add the cross filter 'Account without Contacts'. It will display all those accounts which are having no contacts.

On your Accounts report, click on "Add" Multi-Button and select "Cross Filters." and select the above criteria. Please find the attached screenshot for same.
[image]

Answer (score -2):

> With the introduction of the Cross Filtering functionality in  Enterprise, Unlimited and Developer Editions. These organizations now have access to run a report to identify Accounts Without Contact records. The Cross Filters will permit you to include a sub-scope within an Accounts report to narrow the results to only those Accounts without Contacts.

1. On your Accounts report, click Customize to enter the Report Builder.
2. Click on the "Add" Multi-Button and select "Cross Filters."
3. In the Cross Filter section now displayed, select Accounts without Contacts.

Once in place, it will narrow the scope of the report to only those Accounts lacking Contacts.

Please follow the below link for your requirement.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000003804&language=en_US&type=1